# Why is Craft loading jQuery via cpresources? And can I stop it?

Tags: cache, optimization

I've been doing some performance checks on a website I'm building, and noticed that jQuery 3.5.1 is being loaded via cpresources:

[image: Sources pabel]

Why is it doing this? And can I stop it? I'm already loading jQuery 3.5.1 in my `scripts.js` file (combined with some other stuff and minified using gulp & webpack).

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: I do ya... come to think of it, I bet Wheel Form is the culprit

Answer (score 1):

If any of your image transforms have not previously been processed they will make a call to `/cpresources/...` To prevent this, generate all your transforms before page load with the [generateTransformsBeforePageLoad](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#generatetransformsbeforepageload) config setting:

```
'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true
```

Comment: What do image transforms have to do with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot looks like FE, not BE.

This happens when you use `{% js on load %}` or `{% js on ready %}`

For now I switched to `{% js %}` and wrapped my script with `jQuery(function ($) { ... })`